# Find count of categories in one column using another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set just like below. I want to find out the total number of matches played by India against each opponent?

```
        date      Team_1     Team_2     Winner     Margin    Ground
0  04-Jan-10  Bangladesh  Sri Lanka  Sri Lanka  7 wickets     Dhaka
1  05-Jan-10       India  Sri Lanka  Sri Lanka  5 wickets     Dhaka
2  07-Jan-10  Bangladesh      India      India  6 wickets     Dhaka
3  08-Jan-10  Bangladesh  Sri Lanka  Sri Lanka  9 wickets     Dhaka
4  10-Jan-10       India  Sri Lanka      India  8 wickets     Dhaka
5  11-Jan-10  Bangladesh      India      India  6 wickets     Dhaka
6  13-Jan-10       India  Sri Lanka  Sri Lanka  4 wickets     Dhaka
7  22-Jan-10   Australia   Pakistan  Australia  5 wickets  Brisbane
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  People will be happy to help, but you need to show what you’ve tried so far, and exactly where you’re stuck.  There’s lots of advice on how to ask your question in the Help Centre https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: are you looking for `output =  pd.crosstab(df['Team_1'],df['Team_2'])` ? if not please add an expected output for your question: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: No pd.crosstab is not very useful. I have already tried that. What I basically want is to may be have a dictionary like below                                                                          {'Sri Lanka' :30, 'Australia' : 23,  and so on} i.e. keys are the names of the opponent countries and values resemble the total number of matches palyed by India against these countries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) , then filtering out `India` from the result using [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html)

```
m = df[['Team_1','Team_2']]
d = m[m.eq('India').any(1)].stack().value_counts().loc[lambda x:x.index!='India'].to_dict()
```

Or in 1 line :

```
d1= (df.loc[df.eq('India').any(1),['Team_1','Team_2']]
       .stack().value_counts().loc[lambda x:x.index!='India'].to_dict())
```

---

```
print(d)
#output -> {'Sri Lanka': 3, 'Bangladesh': 2}
```

Comment: Can you please explain any(1) here?

Comment: @SudeshnaDutta that is any across `axis=1`.so it checks if any of team 1 or team2 is india and return True. So since we are interested only in India team, we filter only those relevant rows

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you want must have duplicate entries (permutation vs combination), so start by doubling the dataframe while reversing the orientation of the teams. Then just group by the two team columns and count pairs:

```
pd.concat([scores, scores.rename(columns={"Team_1": "Team_2", "Team_2": "Team_1"})])
  [['Team_1', 'Team_2', 'date']]
  .groupby(["Team_1", "Team_2"])
  .count()

                       date
Team_1     Team_2          
Australia  Pakistan       1
Bangladesh India          2
           SriLanka       2
India      Bangladesh     2
           SriLanka       3
Pakistan   Australia      1
SriLanka   Bangladesh     2
           India          3
```